# Tweepy error after turned to .exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe, tweepy

So I just finished writing this tkinter program in python, everything works perfectly with no errors but when I turned it to an .exe I am getting this error :

```
  File "tweepy\binder.pyc", line 239, in _call
  File "tweepy\binder.pyc", line 189, in execute
  tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 2] No such   file or directory
```

everything works fine in the .py and no errors occure , I can't find any solutions for this on the internet someone help please.
Can someone please help me with this I haven't found any answers !!

Comment: If you search for "185090050" on this site, there are very many answers. Have you read them all to see if they help?

Comment: yea i looked at them and tried a lot but it just isn't working

Comment: @BryanOakley can you please help me with this I'm getting nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally solved my own problem it's the only solution I managed to find out by myself , might not be the best but it works so I am going to explain it step by step so anyone else who has the same problem does'nt have to go through what I've been through :
 Go to the tweepy folder and find binder.py open it and in it find :

```
try:
     resp = self.session.request(self.method,
                                 full_url,
                                 data=self.post_data,
                                 timeout=self.api.timeout,
                                 auth=auth,
                                 proxies=self.api.proxy,
                                 )
```

then add verify='cacert.pem' at the end so it looks like this :

```
try:
     resp = self.session.request(self.method,
                                 full_url,
                                 data=self.post_data,
                                 timeout=self.api.timeout,
                                 auth=auth,
                                 proxies=self.api.proxy,
                                 verify='cacert.pem')
```

save it ,now you need to modify binder.pyc also because it's what py2exe uses when compiling , to do that create a new script and in it type :

```
import py_compile

py_compile.compile('path_to_binder.py')
```

(it would be better to backup binder.py and binder.pyc before any modifications)

now put the script and binder.py (modded one) in the same folder (the path in the script must be to the binder.py in this folder) then run the script

Take the generated binder.pyc and put it in the tweepy folder where the old binder.pyc was.

Now run py2exe like you would and when it is done find the 'cacert.pem' and place it in the 'dist' folder where your .exe is , run the .exe and everything should work perfectly.